# What's the meaning of the symbol "?" in awk user defined function

Tags: linux, function, awk

Dear stackOverflow community,
Here is the code from cut&tag tutorial [text](https://yezhengstat.github.io/CUTTag_tutorial/#34_Assess_mapped_fragment_size_distribution_%5BRequired%5D). I can't understand the meaning of the code for awk user defined function,

```
awk -F'\t' 'function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)} {print abs($9)}'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: that looks like javascript ternary operator and an implementation of absolute value

Comment: I's the ternary operator, common to many programming languages, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the conditional operator. `x ? y : z` is mostly equivalent to `if (x) { y } else { z }`

This means the function is equivalent to:

```
function abs(x){if(x < 0.0) { return -x; } else { return x; }}
```